# SBT not passing credentials when publishing to Artifactory

Tags: sbt, artifactory

I am coding a Java project and I'm automating the build and the publishing to JFrog Artifactory using SBT.

Whenever it's time to publish to Artifactory I want to do it using the Ivy directory layout and obviously publish the Ivy XML file along with the jar. I managed to achieve this by using the following lines in the build.sbt file:

```
crossPaths := false
publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://<Artifactory IP>:<Artifactory Port>/artifactory/org.project.my")
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
publishMavenStyle := false
```

However it only works when anonymous users are allowed to deploy into Artifactory. I realized that sbt is not really passing my credentials to Artifactory but, instead, logging in as anonymous.

My `$HOME/.ivy2/.credentials` file looks like this:

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
host=http://<Artifactory IP>:<Artifactory Port>/artifactory/org.project.my
user=<my user name>
password=<my user name>
```

However, if I change the Artifactory configuration in order to prevent anonymous users from deploying new Artifacts, when I run "sbt publish" I get the following output:

```
[error] Unable to find credentials for [Artifactory Realm @ <Artifactory IP>].
java.io.IOException: Access to URL http://<Artifactory IP>:<Artifactory Port>/artifactory//org.project.my/org/project/my/project-my/1.0.0/project-my-1.0.0.jar was refused by the server: Unauthorized
```

The Artifactory request.log file then contains:

```
20160219011657|319|REQUEST|10.0.2.2|anonymous|PUT|/org.project.my/org/project/my/project-my/1.0.0/project-my-1.0.0.jar|HTTP/1.1|401|24978
```

I have also tried passing the credentials manually instead of using a file:

```
credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "localhost", "<USERNAME>", "<PASS>")
```

But I am getting the same result.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
host=<Artifactory IP>
```

old answer (doesn't work):

```
host=<Artifactory IP>:<Artifactory port>
```

Comment: Thank you Ed!

Your answer is very close to the solution! It worked by doing host=<Artifactory IP> (without the port). 

Please edit your answer and I will mark it as the answer to my question.

Comment: OK, so a summary for those reading it: you do not need to specify the port, or use "http" or "https" or even add the path to your project in the .credentials file. Just add the hostname/IP.

Answer (score 3):

I had a different problem: I had the wrong `realm` set on my `.credentials` file.

Looking at the error output from `sbt`, I was able to figure out that I should use:

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
```

Error shows the expected values for `realm` and `host`:

```
[error] Unable to find credentials for [Artifactory Realm @ myhost].
```

Comment: Yes I had my realm set to
    realm="Artifactory Realm"
with quotes, which didn't work